# How to achieve this in pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have two dataframes `df1` and `df2' :-` df1` :-

| Date | ID | total calls |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 24-02-2021 | 1 | 15 |
| 22-02-2021 | 1 | 25 |
| 20-02-2021 | 3 | 100 |
| 21-02-2021 | 4 | 30 |

`df2`:

| Date | ID | total calls | match_flag |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 24-02-2021 | 1 | 16 | 1 |
| 22-02-2021 | 1 | 25 | 1 |
| 20-02-2021 | 3 | 99 | 1 |
| 24-02-2021 | 2 | 80 | not_found |
| 21-02-2021 | 4 | 25 | 0 |

I want to first match based on Id and Date if both matches I want to check for an addional condition of total calls and if the difference between `total calls` in `df1` and `df2` is +-1 then I want to consider that row as match and update the flag and if it does not satisfy the +-1 condition want to update the flag to 0 and if that date for the *ID* is not found in `df1` then update to `not_found`

Updating the `df1` and `df2` matched on `ID` and `DateId`

`df1`:

| ID | Call_Date | TId | StartTime | EndTime | total calls | Type | Indicator | DateId |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 562124 | 18-10-2021 | 480271 | 18-10-2021 | 18-10-2021 | 1 | Regular Call | SA | 20211018 |
|  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |  |

`df2` :

| ID | total calls | DateId | Start_Time | End_Time | Indicator | Type | match_flag |  |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 562124 | 0 | 20211018 | 2021-10-18T13:06:00.000+0000 | 2021-10-18T13:07:00.000+0000 | AD | R | not_found |  |

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `merge`:

```
s = df2.merge(df1, on=['Date', 'ID'], how='left')['total calls_y']

df2['match_flag'] = (df2['total calls']
                     .sub(s).abs().le(1) # is absolute diff ≤ 1?
                     .astype(int)        # convert to int
                     .mask(s.isna(), 'not_found') # mask missing
                    )
```

output:

```
         Date  ID  total calls match_flag
0  24-02-2021   1           16          1
1  22-02-2021   1           25          1
2  20-02-2021   3           99          1
3  24-02-2021   2           80  not_found
4  21-02-2021   4           25          0
```

Comment: This didint work for me. It gives records which are thre as not found.Neither the date nor the ID is unoique either in `df1` nor `df2'. So we need to take Date+ ID combination

Comment: Can you update the example?

Comment: This is a sample but when I run it on full dataframe, it doesn't seem to work . Which are found are tagged as not found . I don't  seem to understand why

Comment: Yes I get it, so can you update the example to make it more representative of the real data?

Comment: I have updated.